# "The connection was reset" in PHP-PDO

Tags: php, pdo, freetds

I am trying to access SQL Window Server from Linux (ubuntu 12.04) server by PHP PDO extension, but showing me "The connection was reset" from the browser.

Code is -

```
 try {
        self::$instance = new PDO('odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=192.168.0.21; Port=1433; Database=MSSQLTips; UID=XXXX; PWD=XXXXX');
        self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
        self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);       

      } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            trigger_error($error->getMessage());
      }
```

And the access code is

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tblEmployee where Employee_Id = ?';       
$sth = $this->db->prepare($query);               
$sth->execute(array('1557'));
$result = $sth->fetch();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); die;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in PHP. Refer to [bug report 64483](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64483) for more information.

As an alternative to pdo_odbc you can use the pdo_dblib driver to access a MS SQL Server from PHP on Linux. Refer to the [PHP documentation on pdo_dblib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

I have adjusted your code to use dblib.

```
try { 
    self::$instance = new PDO ("dblib:host=192.168.0.21:1433;dbname=MSSQLTips","XXXX","XXXXX");
    self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
    self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);       

  } catch (PDOException $ex) {
      $msg = htmlentities($ex->getMessage());    
      trigger_error($msg);
  }
```

And then:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tblEmployee where Employee_Id = ?';       
$sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
$sth->bindValue(1, "1557", PDO::PARAM_INT);               
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
if($result === false) {
    throw new Exception("Unable to fetch result.");
}

try {
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $msg = htmlentities($ex->getMessage());
    trigger_error($msg,E_WARNING);
}
```